# Converting keywords to tags within tag wiki: acceptable?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I've come across multiple tag wiki edits ([sample](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10307891)) that simply convert keywords into tags. I personally see little value in converting keywords to tags, but that may be valuable to other users.

Are these sorts of edits good/acceptable, or are they too minor of a change?